# How to programmatically ignore syntax errors in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

So just a basic question. I want to know if you can ignore syntax errors in code? Especially in the asp.net framework. So lets say that notorious red squiggly line makes an appearance, how can one just ignore it? (I know it is there for good reason but just for research purposes). Take the very very simple example below. There is an imaginary red squiggly line under the c variable. How to make the compiler ignore it?

```
int i = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors is the compiler saying: "I literally have no idea what you want me to do." The closest thing to "ignoring" them is to just executed the last compilation that worked. And as anyone who did early WPF debugging can tell you, that is a terrible idea.